# Smart input with jQuery mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

I want to create a smart input field for phone numbers with the jQuery mask plugin.

If the focus is in the input and index #4 value = 91 input, show

```
$("#phone").mask("+97(912)1234567");
```

and if 0912 back in to 912 and remove 0 from the mask in realtime

My code:

```
var smart_input = setInterval(function () {
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    var phone_element = $('#phone');

    if (phone.indexOf('09') == 0 && phone.length != 0) {

        var prefix = phone.substring(1);

        $('#phone').mask('(999) 999 9999');
        phone_element.val(prefix);
    } else if (phone.indexOf('91') == 0 && phone.length != 0) {

        var prefix = phone.substring(1);
        $('#phone').mask('(999) 999 9999');
        phone_element.val(prefix);

    }


}, 1);
```

Comment: So what we are supposed to do ? Please state your issue

Comment: i dont know how can i fix this code! i want if i input this number +9709124545275 in input box back in to +97 (912) 4545275

Comment: First thing to do is get rid of that `setInterval`. That's just a waste of browser resources. Instead, consider modifying the output on [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change) or on [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress)

Answer (score 0):

In same scenario I took [this](http://www.smartwebby.com/DHTML/phone_no_validation_reg.asp#explanation) as a reference . Please try